# The Multi-Room Muddy Forehead Puzzle with Varied Color Perception

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, search-algorithms

Imagine there are n children, and they are divided into three separate rooms (Room A, Room B, Room C) without knowing how many children are in each room. As before, their foreheads are marked with either red or blue mud, but now the father also adds a third color, green.

Furthermore, some children are wearing glasses that allow them to see only one or two colors. Others can see all three colors. Everyone knows that these variations exist, but they don't know who has which ability.

The father's announcement is now: "At least one of you in each room has a red muddy forehead, a blue muddy forehead, and a green muddy forehead."

The children are asked the same question as before, but now they are asked this question in sequence within their own room, and the answers are broadcasted to the other rooms.

Here's how it might unfold:

First few rounds: The children try to deduce information based on the answers within their own room and the information broadcasted from the other rooms. They must consider not only the colors they see but also the unknown distribution of children across the rooms and the unknown viewing abilities of the other children.

Middle rounds: As the rounds progress, children might begin to deduce information about the distribution of children in the rooms, the viewing abilities of certain children, and potentially some information about the colors of mud on the foreheads in the other rooms.

Final rounds: After many rounds of questioning, some children may be able to deduce the color of mud on their own forehead based on the complex interplay of all these factors.

How many children have muddy foreheads?What is the minimum number of rounds required for any child to deduce their forehead's color?